# Magento2 store switcher not working when enable the add stores codes

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3, store-switcher

magento2 store switcher not working when enable the Add Store Code to Urls in configuration.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have Error Log?

Comment: no error message in error log